# URI multilingual CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, multilingual

We're using Codeingiter library i18n ([link](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n)) to create a multilingual site.

Before this, we had for example www.thedomain.com/register and register was a function in our controller. Now when we put this library it grabs the domain, the language string, the controller's name and the functions name: www.thedomain.com/es/homegf/register (where homegf is our controller).

We want this URI's to work without the name of our controller on it (www.thdomain.com/es/register) like in the librarie's examples but we think the problem is in our routes.php.

This is what we have in routes.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = "homegf";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['^(en|es|de)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['^(en|es|de)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

This is our .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|files|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can find our code to review it at https://bitbucket.org/ticketcomunicacion/grinfood/src/17ddde60e340a1f2bc389f54ec579e1e903ee86b?at=multilenguaje

Comment: So if you don't get rerouted to where you want, where DO you end up?

Comment: The content that i found in www.thedomain.com/es/homegf/register, i want to www.thedomain.com/es/register, i want to disappear homegf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in our routes.

This is how we managed to make it work:

```
$route['^es/(.+)$'] = "homegf/$1";
$route['^en/(.+)$'] = "homegf/$1";

$route['^es$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^en$'] = $route['default_controller'];

$route['(:any)'] = 'homegf/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

**as i understand , you want  the controller url without controller name .**

if you want to change the URL from your controller name to other ,

in your routes.php write the following

```
$route['homegf/register'] = "register";
```

and you can access

domain.com/es/register

Comment: The site is dinamical, there are plenty of functions like register (validate, forgot_password, new_order ...) the plan is not having to write each one...istead using regular expression or something

Comment: try to add

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /homegf/$1 [L]

on htaccess

Comment: yes, i tried but doesn`t work, i think is something in routes.php, because www.thdomain.com/es/register show 404 error page (not found)

Comment: can you please explain me , what is the current url and how you want it .

Comment: the current url: www.thedomain.com/es/homegf/register and I want www.thedomain.com/es/register  ; before putting the library the web worked as www.thedomain.com/register and just adding route[(:any)]='homegf/$1' in routes.php file

Comment: This is our repo with the code if you want to take a look https://bitbucket.org/ticketcomunicacion/grinfood/src/17ddde60e340a1f2bc389f54ec579e1e903ee86b?at=multilenguaje